# Normalizing BatchDataset in Tensorflow 2.3

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` from TF 2.3 to load images from directories (train/test split). What I get is a tf.data.Dataset (`tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset`actually) object with shapes:

```py
train_ds.take(1)
# <TakeDataset shapes: ((None, 256, 256, 3), (None, 6)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>
```

```py
for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
    print(images.shape)
    print(images[0])
# (32, 256, 256, 3)
# tf.Tensor(
# [[[225.75  225.75  225.75 ]
#   [225.75  225.75  225.75 ]
#   [225.75  225.75  225.75 ]
#   ...
#   [215.    214.    209.   ]
#   [215.    214.    209.   ]
#   [215.    214.    209.   ]]
#
#  ...], shape=(256, 256, 3), dtype=float32)
```

I cannot figure out how to normalize images (`/= 255`) with that Dataset object. I tried playing with `/=` operator itself, `map` and `apply` methods and even casting that object to list as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57791851/cast-tensorflow-2-0-batchdataset-to-numpy-array). Nothing seems to work and I would really like to solve this problem at Dataset level instead of adding normalization layer to my network.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show how did you use `map` to normalize the image from the tf dataset

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this way:

```
def process(image,label):
    image = tf.cast(image/255. ,tf.float32)
    return image,label

ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(IMAGE_DIR)
ds = ds.map(process)
```

Comment: I really believe I did something similar (found that in another question) and it didn't work. This piece of code seems to work though. Thanks a lot, turns out that was my silly mistake then

Comment: It seems that this code changes dataset type to `MapDataset` which raises an error later (i.e. MapDataset has no attribute class_names that I use), but normalization itself is working

Comment: Sure, it's here: https://github.com/mtszkw/garbage/blob/master/garbage2.ipynb I've already fixed the issue with class_names (by providing list of names explicitly).