# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'BatchDataset' and 'float'

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to divide 'train' by 255 to normalize, but i get the following error:

" TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'BatchDataset' and 'float' "

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
path=r'C:\Users\faisa\Desktop\sample_cropped' #Change this to work with your directory


batch_size = 1
img_height = 28
img_width = 28

train = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(path,
        validation_split = 0.15,
        subset = "training",
        seed = 123,
        color_mode="grayscale",
        image_size = (img_height, img_width),
        batch_size = batch_size)

X = train/255.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Normalizing BatchDataset in Tensorflow 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63572451/normalizing-batchdataset-in-tensorflow-2-3)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are attempting to divide a float with a non-divisible type, Dataset.

[tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory#returns)

Comment: how can i make it divisible?

Comment: @Trijopa From reading the docs, you’re getting different data depending on the label attribute, so you will need to access the right values.